# Sorting a pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, series

I am trying to figure out how to sort the Series generated as a result of a groupby aggregation in a smart way.

I generate an aggregation of my DataFrame like this:

```
means = df.testColumn.groupby(df.testCategory).mean()
```

This results in a Series. I now try to sort this by value, but get an error:

```
means.sort()
...
-> Exception: This Series is a view of some other array, to sort in-place you must create a copy
```

I then try creating a copy:

```
meansCopy = Series(means)
meansCopy.sort()
-> Exception: This Series is a view of some other array, to sort in-place you must create a copy
```

How can I get this sort working?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use `sort_values`, i.e. `means = means.sort_values()`. [***Pandas v0.17+***]

---

#### (Very old answer, pre-v0.17 / 2015)

pandas used to use `order()` method: `means = means.order()`.

Comment: All this .sort_index(), .argsort() and so on is very confusing... doc does not say much...

Comment: Agree with @smci. If anyone could edit this answer to explain it better, that would be much appreciated. I ran into this problem with a series selected out of a data frame (as opposed to something from groupby).

Comment: You can use `.sort(inplace=False)`, which is equivalent to `.order()`. The difference is that `order` create a new Series object and `sort` does not by default.