# Sort a pandas Series by the index

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

I have a Pandas dataframe called `pd`, and I extract the number of unique values in one of the columns of this dataframe using the following command:

```
b = df.groupby('Region').size()
```

b is a Pandas series object and looks like this:

```
In [48]: b
Out[48]: 
Region
0          8
1         25
11         1
2         41
3         23
4         15
5         35
6         24
7         27
8         50
9         55
N         10
```

I am trying to plot a barchart of this series, however, I would like to sort it first based on the first column (because of that 11 between 1 and 2), which will be the x axis labels. I tried passing the sort command, but it sorts the series based on the values in the second column:

```
b.sort()

In [48]: b
Out[54]: 
Region
11         1
0          8
N         10
4         15
3         23
6         24
1         25
7         27
5         35
2         41
8         50
9         55
```

Well, is there a way to sort this series based on the first column?

Comment: This question is regarding sorting a pandas Series by its _index_. If you wish to know how to sort a Series by values, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12133075/sorting-a-pandas-series/54299881#54299881).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to convert your index to an object index, because it's currently sorting lexicographically, not numerically:

```
In [97]: s = read_clipboard(header=None)

In [98]: news = s.rename(columns=lambda x: ['Region', 'data'][x])

In [99]: news
Out[99]:
   Region  data
0       0     8
1       1    25
2      11     1
3       2    41
4       3    23
5       4    15
6       5    35
7       6    24
8       7    27
9       8    50
10      9    55
11      N    10

In [100]: news_converted = news.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)

In [101]: news_converted
Out[101]:
    Region  data
0        0     8
1        1    25
2       11     1
3        2    41
4        3    23
5        4    15
6        5    35
7        6    24
8        7    27
9        8    50
10       9    55
11     NaN    10

In [102]: news_converted.loc[11, 'Region'] = 'N'

In [103]: news_converted_with_index = news_converted.set_index('Region')

In [104]: news_converted_with_index
Out[104]:
        data
Region
0.0        8
1.0       25
11.0       1
2.0       41
3.0       23
4.0       15
5.0       35
6.0       24
7.0       27
8.0       50
9.0       55
N         10

In [105]: news_converted_with_index.sort_index()
Out[105]:
        data
Region
0.0        8
1.0       25
2.0       41
3.0       23
4.0       15
5.0       35
6.0       24
7.0       27
8.0       50
9.0       55
11.0       1
N         10
```

There's most likely a better way to create your `Series` so that it doesn't mix index types.

Comment: @Philip Cloud thanks! this seems to solve the problem of sorting, now I am looking into constructing this series in a better way as you mentioned. This whole thing started with trying to count the unique values in a df column, which has that 'N' as one of the data values.

Answer (score 16):

You are looking for [sort_index](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sort_index.html?highlight=sort#pandas.Series.sort_index):

```
In [80]: b.sort_values()
Out[80]: 
6     1
11    2
9     2
1     4
10    4
2     5
3     6
4     7
8     8
5     9
dtype: int64

In [81]: b.sort_index()
Out[81]: 
1     4
2     5
3     6
4     7
5     9
6     1
8     8
9     2
10    4
11    2
dtype: int64
```

Comment: `sort_index()` still gives me the same output with `Out[48]` above, 11 is still between 1 and 2. It's like pandas is treating the index values as text. I do have `N` as one of the index values though.

Answer (score 8):

There is only 1 'column' of values. The first 'column' is the index.
[Docs are here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/basics.html#sorting-by-index-and-value)

```
In [8]: s = Series([3,2,1],index=[1,3,2])

In [9]: s
Out[9]: 
1    3
3    2
2    1
dtype: int64
```

Sort by the index

```
In [10]: s.sort_index()
Out[10]: 
1    3
2    1
3    2
dtype: int64
```

Sort by values

```
In [11]: s.sort_values()
Out[11]: 
2    1
3    2
1    3
dtype: int64
```

Comment: I left this comment to bdiamente's reply, but here it goes as well: `sort_index()` still gives me the same output with `Out[48]` above, 11 is still between 1 and 2. It's like pandas is treating the index values as text. I do have `N` as one of the index values though.

Comment: they COULD be text, how did you create it?

Comment: @marillion Your values are text. You'll need to convert the numbers to numeric types and use an object dtype Index. Then `sort_index()` will do what you want, although there's most likely a better way to do this without having mixed numeric/string indices.

Comment: @Jeff the df was constructed using pd.read_csv('filename.csv'), then I used `groupby` to count the number of unique values. Maybe the 'N' value in the data resulted in an index with text type.

Comment: ahh...didn't see the N, yes for sure, its automatically text that way. Best to put thin in a DataFrame, replace that value with a number and you will be good to go.

Comment: @Jeff, that's what I did at the end. N is now 111. I will probably play with the bar chart tickmarks later in matplotlib. Thanks for the help!

Comment: order was deprecated quite a while ago - use .sprt_values()